# Iterate on an array and interpolating some "text" after every nth element

Tags: python, arrays

I have created an array of [1-25] and I am trying to Iterate on an array printing to the screen each element, interpolating "this is a test" as a text after every 5th element.

tried so far:

```
insert_text = "This is test"
# Create array
value_arr = range(1, 26)
cnt = 0
#loop and insert text to the array. + 1
for i in range(len(value_arr) + 1):
    if i % 5 == 0 and i != 0:
    value_arr.insert(i + cnt, insert_text)
    cnt+=1
 print value_arr
```

Comment: For starters, `for i in range(len...` is redundant. You can simply write `for i in value_arr:`. Then, do you have to insert the text into the array? Can you not just print it?

Comment: `value_arr = ["This is test" if (i+1) % 5 == 0  and i != 0 else x for i,x in enumerate(value_arr)]`?

Comment: So every 5 iterations it prints the text ? Maybe your overthinking this set up an array of 25 indices and a counter to iterate through starting at 1 then just say if the counters remainder is 0 then print if not don't ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for nbr in range(1,26):
    string = str(nbr)
    if nbr % 5 == 0:
        string += " This is a test"
    print string
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you increment i AND cnt in the loop (i is automatically incremented by the for ... in range loop and cnt is incremented manually by you)
So when you reached the 20th element, you set the text into the 40th element, which doesnt exist...

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(array)+1):
    if i%5==0:
        print("this is a test")
        print(array[i])
    else:
        print(array[i])
```

Walkthrough: Case by if the the index is a multiple of 5